# Why does Mamp Pro ask for the Phalcon extension 32 bits if I have Windows 64 bits?

Tags: windows, mamp, phalcon

I’m installing Phalcon on a Windows 64 bits with Mamp Pro, but Mamp ask the Phalcon extension 32 bits, then I used the Phalcon extension 32 bits and apparently it’s ok, because the phpinfo() show it.
The problem is that at the moment run the application it throw an error:
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Phalcon\Loader' not found in C:\MAMP\htdocs\MyProject\api\public\index.php:32

Any idea? Thank you so much!

Comment: is your version of mamp compiled as 32-bit?

Comment: Thank you for answer me. I really don´t know, I’m using the last version for Windows, I mean 4.1. From here https://www.mamp.info/en/downloads/